# Magento 2. Declarative Schema. How to uninstall a patch without uninstalling the module?

Tags: magento2, declarative-schema

The official [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/) say this.

> Revertable data patch - A patch that can be reverted as a module or patch is uninstalled or deleted.

I know that Revertable patches must implement `Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface` and when a module is un-installed the logic in the revert() method is called.

How can one revert a Patch without uninstalling the module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the docs are incorrect|confusing. There is another page in the  [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html#reverting-data-patches) that clearly states

> Magento does not allow you to revert a particular module data patch

Answer (score 4):

[vitoriodachef](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/276779) is indeed correct, unfortunately there is no CLI command available to undo a data patch.

Depending on what kind of data patch you have made the quickest way is to call the `revert()` function from your patch:

```
//..patch class

    public function apply(): void
    {
        $this->revert();
        return; // (optional, to only execute revert and not patch)

        //...your patch code
    }

    public function revert(): void
    {
        //...your revert code
    }
```

If you have already executed your patch before then run the following query so that when you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated` your patch is executed again

```
DELETE FROM patch_list 
    WHERE patch_name LIKE '%Vendor\Module%' 
    ORDER BY patch_id DESC 
    LIMIT 1;
```